# Good maze creation software?

Tags: puzzle-creation, mazes

I'm trying to make a maze for a puzzle hunt, and I can't find any good software for creating them.

> I seek an appropriate *simple drawing tool*, not a program to automatically create the maze.

I just want to make something simple like this:

[image: maze]

but the trouble is that all of the software I can find is either absurdly complicated or it only allows you to set a couple parameters and generate a maze. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user902383: I specifically said I didn't want auto-generated ones

Comment: You could always just use MS-Paint and scale down to pixel size and set the image to the size restrictions....

Comment: I think what you want is a software that lets you assemble blocks of default maze sections like lego, is it?

Comment: @Deusovi Could you please revise your question to state more precisely what you are looking for. Until then, I have voted to close this as too broad as it is difficult to understand what you are asking. Also your image is not properly loaded in this question.

Comment: @MarkN I think the edit by BmyGuest greatly clarified the need if OP agrees with it.

Comment: Have you tried pen and (squared) paper?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're just looking for a tool to help you manually lay out your own custom mazes, you can just use spreadsheet software such as Excel or OpenOffice Calc. Set the grid size so that the cells are squares, and then draw the borders in.

For Excel, if you switch to the Page Layout view you can set the row/column sizes in units such as cm, which will enable you to have a square grid. Then use Borders > Draw Border.

Comment: I was going to (well have) suggested the same using word, but trying it out, Excel is more convenient ;c)   +1 from me for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the Excel suggestion, but I use WinWord (if the maze is not too big.)

Step 1) Insert a table of cells you want, i.e. 25 x 25. Use a fairly small "fixed" cell width. (i.e. 0.5cm)

[image: Add Table]

Step 2) Select table and properties and set row height to same as cell width. (0.5)

[image: Table row height]

Now you have the perfect "grid" to work on, and you can use the "Draw table" tool to set the border to the lines you want.

[image: Table]
[image: Tool]

[image: Draw with tool]

Answer (score 2):

simpler is to draw a path with a brush in a photo software.

draw the whole path with all the dead ends.

then select the whole and invert or make negative !

[image]

Comment: This is actually quite simple, especially if you have proper drawing software and hold shift while drawing (for straight lines)

Comment: I want something that gives output in the format in the question. I'd prefer it to look "professional".

Answer (score 2):

If s1 need a grid maze using cell drawing:
https://craftdesignonline.com/pattern-grid/

It also supports importing/converting existing image to.

[image]